# URL Safe C# AES Encryption

Tags: c#, .net-core, encryption, aes

I am having issues creating an encrypted string that I am passing in a URL. Where I am either getting incorrect characters after decrypting or the error. "The input data is not a complete block"

Here is my class to encrypt and decrypt my string:

```cs
    public static class StringCipher
    {
        public static string Encrypt(string s)
        {
            return AesProvider(s, (aes, raw) =>
            {
                using var ms = new MemoryStream();
                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
                }

                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            });
        }

        public static string Decrypt(string s)
        {
            return AesProvider(s, (aes, raw) =>
            {
                using var ms = new MemoryStream();
                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
                }
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            });

        }
        
        private static string AesProvider(string s, Func<Aes, byte[], string> fn)
        {
            var raw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
            using var aes = Aes.Create();

            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            aes.KeySize = 128;                // in bits
            aes.Key     = new byte[128 / 8];  // 16 bytes for 128 bit encryption
            aes.IV      = new byte[128 / 8];  // AES needs a 16-byte IV
            aes.Mode    = CipherMode.CBC;

            return fn.Invoke(aes, raw);
        }
    }
```

Example usage would be as such:

```cs
var encrypted = StringCipher.Encrypt("my payload");
```

I then use `Base64UrlEncoder` which I understand is a URL-safe base64 encoding.

```cs
var url = $"https://example.com?code={Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(encrypted)}"
```

When I want to decrypt it, I am attempting to do the following:

```cs
// https://example.com?code=a5e52f...
var decoded = Base64UrlEncoder.Decode(code);
var plainText = StringCipher.Decrypt(decoded); // expect "my payload"
```

I know I must be making a silly mistake here.

Questions:

1. Why is this implementation not working correctly?
2. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: because not every byte sequence is a valid UTF-8 character sequence, and since `Encoding.UTF8` by default just ignores invalid sequences, then when you turn those bytes into a string with `GetString`, you end up with some of the data missing.

Using Base64 is the right way to go, but you're doing it wrong: you want to pass a byte array to `Base64UrlEncoder.Encode`, not a string. Don't do the `GetString` step, just pass the result of `ms.ToArray()` directly. The whole point of Base64 is to turn arbitrary binary data into text, you don't need an intermediate conversion to string.

Similarly, when decrypting, you should use `Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes` to turn that string into bytes, and then decrypt those bytes.

Here's what the final result would look like. First off, I reworked the `AesProvider` method to just return the `Aes` object directly:

```
private static Aes CreateProvider()
{
    var aes = Aes.Create();

    // etc.

    return aes;
}
```

Then, here's `Encrypt`:

```
public static string Encrypt(string s)
{
    using var aes = CreateProvider();
    
    using var ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        var raw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
        cs.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
    }

    return Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(ms.ToArray());
}
```

And here's Decrypt:

```
public static string Decrypt(string s)
{
    using var aes = CreateProvider();

    using var ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        var raw = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(s);
        cs.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
    }
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Hello Etienne, I try to change the code of Joepour with your suggestions but with no result. I think I do some mistake. Can you provide the modified code?